# Test JPA repository for void functions and updates and deletes

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, testing, junit

I working on writing tests for a crud application. I need to test the service and repository for Delete and Update statements. How would I go about mocking the repository for delete and update since they won't be returning data?

For example:

```java
@Override
public void makeUserActive(long userId) {
   try {
       Optional<UserEntity> userEntityList = usersJpaRepository.findById(userId);
       UserEntity userEntity = userEntityList.get();
       userEntity.setIsActive(1);
       usersJpaRepository.save(userEntity);
   } catch (Exception e) {
       logger.error("Cant make active user", e);
   }
 }
```

How do i test the service that mocks this repository and also the repository itself since it wont be returning a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is what is the *thing* you want to be tested?
If you would like to test your repository you can achieve this by using Springs `@DataJpaTest`. see [Integration Testing With @DataJpaTest](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing#integration-testing-with-datajpatest)

If you would like to test the logic inside your `makeUserActive`-Method you must make sure to mock your repository.

Assuming the service which contains your `makeUserActive`-Method looks something like this:

```
public class UserService{

    private final UsersJpaRepository usersJpaRepository;

    public UserService(UsersJpaRepository usersJpaRepository) {
        this.usersJpaRepository = usersJpaRepository;
    }

    public void makeUserActive(long userId){
        // your code from your question

    }
}
```

You could write your Unit Test like this:

```
@Test
void makeUserActiveTest(){
    UsersJpaRepository repository = new InMemoryUsersJpaRepository();
    UserEntity user = new UserEntity();
    user = repository.save(user);

    UserService service = new UserService(repository);

    service.makeUserActive(user.getId());

    Optional<UserEntity> activatedUser = repository.findById(user.getId());

    assertTrue(activatedUser.isPresent());
    assertEquals(1, activatedUser.get().isActive());
}
```

The `InMemoryUsersJpaRepository` is a self written Mock which will store all data in an internal Map. The code could look something like this:

```
public class InMemoryUsersJpaRepository extends UsersJpaRepository {

    private Map<Long, UserEntity> users = new HashMap<>();
    private Long idCounter = 1L;

    @Override
    public UserEntity save(UserEntity user) {
        if(user.getId() == null){
            user.setId(idCounter);
            idCounter++;
        }

        users.put(user.getId(), user);

        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<UserEntity> findById(long userId) {
        return Optional.of(users.get(userId));
    }
}
```

This way you will test the logic of your `makeUserActive`-Method which is currently to simply set the `isActivated` Flag on you UserEntity.

---

Also I would like to warn you about the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62666252/7027682) of Mensur Qulami.
The Code in his answer will lead to a passing test but I'am pretty sure it does not test the thing you want to be tested.
You should always test the expected and observable behaviour of your method.
In your case this would be the `isActivated` Flag that should be 1.
The fact that your `makeUserActive`-Method calls the `findById` and `save` Method of the `UsersJpaRepository` is a mere implementation detail and the testing of those generally lead to brittle tests.

Answer (score 1):

For the methods returning `void`, you can simply verify that they have been called. Here's an example, that mocks both an object returning method and `void` returning method.

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class ServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private Repository repository;
    @InjectMocks
    private Service service; // assume that this is your class

    @Test
    void testMakeUserActive() {
        // given:
        final UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();
        // mocks:
        when(repository.findById(1)).thenReturn(Optional.of(userEntity));

        // when:
        service.makeUserActive(1);

        // then:
        verify(repository).findById(1);
        verify(repository).save(userEntity); 
    }
}
```